# Is there a way to presupply git rebase with the list to use for rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

Instead of `git rebase -i` and editing manually is there a possibility to supply `git rebase` with the pick/drop/squash list as a text file, or do I need to redirect GIT_EDITOR to a script that supplies it ?

Comment: Could you explain better what you want to do? maybe with some example.

Comment: Redirect `GIT_EDITOR` to a script (which can be as simple as `GIT_EDITOR='sed -i -e "/COMMITID1/ s/pick/squash/" -e "/COMMITID2/ d"' git rebase -i ...`).

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara the question seems quite clear actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use `GIT_EDITOR` or `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` to edit the file in place.  That program will receive the file name as its argument, and can be a shell command, so you can do something like this:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR='sed -i -e '\''2,$s/^pick/fixup/'\' git rebase
```

The difference between the two editors is that `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` only applies to the rebase todo list, but not to other things like commit messages, whereas `GIT_EDITOR` applies to both.  So, for example, if you want to automatically squash in all squash and fixup commits created by `git commit --squash` and `git commit --fixup` without prompting, you can do this:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=true git rebase -i --autosquash main
```

That automatically accepts the squash and fixup commands without prompting, but still leaves your normal editor for editing commit messages due to squash commits.