# Provide a list of commits to edited for reabase

Tags: git, git-rebase

Is there any possibility to feed a file of commit IDs into the rebase `git rebase -i` command?
I have already analyzed my commits based on the git log and identified the commits that need to be edited and put this commit IDs into a file. Is there any way to feed this directly into rebase as a list of commits that need to be edited? Or do I have to edit the todo list provided by git manually?

Comment: Someone has certainly written a script to do this, but I don't know of a native Git way to do this from the command line.

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66129497/7976758